# Adding multiple values to the same key in perl hash

Tags: perl, hash, key

I have tow hash.

%hash1 :

```
cavallaro; amg; 
gariboldi; amg; 
dalfabbro; mdg_dig; 
valerio; apb_fmtrd;
```

%hash2 :

```
cavallaro; 32; 
gariboldi; 6; 
dalfabbro; 62; 
valerio; 19;
```

I want to combinate them by key like this ;

```
cavallaro; 32; amg; 
gariboldi; 6; amg; 
dalfabbro; 62; mdg_dig; 
valerio; 19; apb_fmtrd;
```

How would I add multiple values for the same key.
Please, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Where in your example do you need multiple values for the same key?

Comment: @choroba yes , i need multiple values for the same key .

Comment: Answer to "Where" shouldn't be "Yes".

Comment: sorry ,@choroba i mean , i want to combine the two hash by the key

Comment: Rolled back changes of the question because they were either incomplete (because the desired output wasn't adjusted too) or unrelated to the existing question.

Answer (score 5):

You can store an array reference at each key:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash1 = qw( cavallaro amg
                gariboldi amg
                dalfabbro mdg_dig
                valerio apb_fmtrd );

my %hash2 = qw( cavallaro 32
                gariboldi 6
                dalfabbro 62
                valerio 19 );

my %r;
for my $k1 (keys %hash1) {
    $r{$k1} = [ $hash2{$k1}, $hash1{$k1} ];
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%r;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'gariboldi' => [
                           '6',
                           'amg'
                         ],
          'valerio' => [
                         '19',
                         'apb_fmtrd'
                       ],
          'dalfabbro' => [
                           '62',
                           'mdg_dig'
                         ],
          'cavallaro' => [
                           '32',
                           'amg'
                         ]
        };
```

Comment: please how can i do the sum of the same values; like 'amg' 6 + 32 ?

Comment: For a new question, ask a new question.